# How to read a text file and add the data to a int array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, text, io

I'm trying to read a text file which contains numbers separated by a comma. When I read using `File.Readline()` I get it to a `string[]`. I need to convert it in to a int array but it gives an error.

The contents of the text file:

> 146429,143689,144380,141523,139572,136930,133714,130011,125843,121110,115974,110363,104367,97909,91245,84218,77008,69626,62058,54445,46942,39436,32146,24932,18359,12601,9039,9776,13638,18314,23221,27728,32142,35941,39577,42657,45692,48180

My code:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(new string[] { " , " }, StringSplitOptions.None); 

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
        valArr[LineCount][i] = Convert.ToInt64(values[i]); // error
    }

    LineCount++;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast and efficient way to read a space separated file of numbers into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952868/fast-and-efficient-way-to-read-a-space-separated-file-of-numbers-into-an-array)

Comment: You should split by `","`, not by `" , "`. Also, why are you converting to Int64?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\test.txt");
        long[] data = ExtractData(sr).ToArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<long> ExtractData(StreamReader sr)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var items = line.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                yield return Convert.ToInt64(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

With my test file (d:\test.txt) holding:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
```

I get the array containing:

```
1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4
```

### EDIT

As Monroe pointed out, I missed the fact you wanted an array of arrays. Here's another version that gives such a jagged array. Still keeping yield in though ;)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\test.txt");
        var data = ExtractData(sr).ToArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<long[]> ExtractData(StreamReader sr)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line.Split(',').Select(i => Convert.ToInt64(i)).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why thank you kind sir!
Following LINQ style for it to keep memory usage down and avoid using other collections. That, and I just like yield return :)

Comment: if i hv to change the code to return a long[][]. hw will it be ? btw thanks helped me a lot

Comment: This extracts all of the values, but doesn't preserve the line number context the OP appears to be striving for.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I've updated my answer to give another option.

Answer (score 1):

Using `List` can help you, and use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to prevent `null exception` in `Convert.ToInt64`

```
var lineArray = new List<List<Int64>>();

foreach (var lineString in File.ReadAllLines("path"))
{
    var line = new List<Int64>();
    string[] values = lineString.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' },  
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    line.AddRange(values.Select(t => Convert.ToInt64(t)));
    lineArray.Add(line);
}
```

and using it:

```
// Array of numbers for specific line
var resultArray = lineArray[lineNumber].ToArray();
```

Comment: Why use a `Dictionary<int, List<Int64>>` instead of a `List<List<Int64>>`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something nearly to:

```
int yourIntArray = 
    new List<string>(RealAllText(fileName)
    .Split(new char[] {',', '\r', '\n', ' '},
    stringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ConvertAll<int>(s => int.Parse(s))
    .ToArray();
```

Of course, for more robustness, `int.Parse` should be replaced with some method that will handle errors in numbers, and so on...

EDIT:

Oh, I just saw that you have lines that are another index to your array...  Well then, this code should be modified in that case, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do. Only thing is that your vallArr should be a two dimensional array that can keep all values. Something like  var valArr = new Int64[x, y];

```
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(new string[] { " , " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                valArr[LineCount, i] = Int64.Parse(values[i]);
            }
            LineCount++;
        }
```